# Get Bluetooth status on Tizen Wearable

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm creating a watch face for my Gear 2 Neo (using `Tizen Wearable SDK`), and I've spent hours looking (with no luck) for a way to determine if the bluetooth is enabled or not (and if possible if it's connected).

I've tried looking at the `Tizen.SystemInfo API` documents, but I can't find anything. I've even tried `tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue();` with "BLUETOOTH" / "NETWORK" as the `property` name, but this doesn't work. It seems the `Tizen.Bluetooth` namespace isn't usable either.

I know there must be a way, as I have seen several watch faces out there that are able to get the status.

Is anyone able to help me out / point me in the right direction?

Edit:

Using `tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();` returns the following: "The application does not have the privilege to call this method"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

To get the bluetooth status, you need to first get the defaultAdapter using following API

```
var blueAdapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();
console.log(blueAdapter); // To log the object
       /* Output of above log
          BluetoothAdapter
          address: ""
          name: ""
          powered: false
          visible: true
       */

if (blueAdapter.powered) {
    // Bluetooth is on, you can off using
    blueAdapter.setPowered(false);
} else {
    // Bluetooth is off, you can switch on using
    blueAdapter.setPowered(true);
}
```

Don't forget to add the privilege in config.xml of your app.

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth.gap"/>
```

Note: Whenever you try to use platform, you need to provide the corresponding privilege in your apps config.xml file

Comment: Using tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter(); returns the following: "The application does not have the privilege to call this method"

Comment: Check modified answer.

You are not mentioning the privileges in your config.xml file thats why you got that error.

Comment: Thanks Srabani, once I added the privilege, it worked well :)

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to check if it is connected to another bluetooth device?